# Creating dynamically different views in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a linearlayout with different relativeview layouts (containing text, image, google map, fragments. Mixed depending on the need) inside it. the views inside linearlayout will vary between 30 to 40 views. It will be mixed type of views.

I found there are two options:

1. Using recycler view with getItemViewType().
2. Directly creating views using layoutinflator.

Which option is good with respect to:

a) it should be fast.

Comment: why it is downvoted. (any thing blunder). I tried to keep it very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RecyclerView for performance gains. We have exact same use case @NY Times and had dramatic improvement in scroll performance when we switched from a linear layout with 30 children to instead be a linear layout  with 30 rows (of about ten different view types)

Its a bit more work to setup but you'll thank yourself later.